# Ethernet Working but No Internet Connection

Tags: macos, networking, dns, macbook, internet-connection

In my office, nearly everybody uses Mac and we have just only one Windows 7 system. Just this morning, all the mac systems (10.8.2) could not connect to the internet but could connect to the network.

When I tried pinging the DNS address, it replied but I can not ping www.google.com on any of the mac systems. If I try creating a new location for the network and enter all the details manually instead of autoConfig, it connects to the internet for like 30 seconds and then shuts off again. The connection still shows green afterall and could still ping the DNS.

I tried killing the mDNSResponder but still same issue.

Kindly help!

Regards

EDIT:
The Windows 7 PC is connected to the internet and I am raising this post using the windows 7 PC

Comment: Is the Windows 7 PC able to access the internet? If not, I would suggest to check your internet connection at your office, since you might be able to reach the router but the router might not be connected to the internet.

Comment: This sounds like the network device the computers are connected to is not connected to the internet.

Comment: The windows 7 PC is connected to the internet and I am raising this post using the Windows 7 PC.

Comment: So all PCs and Macs have a working connection to the Internet, but DNS fails on the Macs but not on the windows PC?

Comment: Yes... DNS Resolve fails ONLY on MAC systems.

Comment: Are you on a domain, peer to peer or using a router?? maybe a fixed ip on PC instead of DHCP?? Firewall?? I think we need more info on this one to try to figure it out.

Comment: Nothing of such... Not on a domain. Just a CISCO Router and a Switch which they are all connected to. Using the network diagnostic tool shows it is connected to the ISP but not to the Internet.